# How can i delete elements in a list with remove order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, maxlength

I have a list like this  `lst = [1,3,5]`  and a major list like `lost =['the' , 'cat' , 'thinks' , 'you' , 'are' , 'crazy' ]`

I want to delete elements in second list based on indexes in the first one . It means i have to remove 'cat' , 'you' and 'crazy' .

The problem is if i use :

```
lost.remove(lost[1])
lost.remove(lost[3])
lost.remove(lost[5])
```

First problem is its not gonna work out!
Because as we remove the first element the length of the list(**named lost**) decreases
and in that way we will remove wrong elements.

Second problem is the list named(**lst**) will not always be [1,3,5] . Its gonna change in length
and in elements .

How can i fix the problem?

Comment: Remove the elements in *descending* index order: 5, 3, 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@np8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3015186/np8) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63074896/how-can-i-delete-elements-in-a-list-based-on-a-list-of-indexes-that-ive-already#comment111538984_63074896), you can remove the elements in *descending* index order like the following:

```py
lst = [1, 3, 5]
lost = ['the', 'cat', 'thinks', 'you', 'are', 'crazy']

for index in reversed(lst):  # descending index order
    del lost[index]

print(lost)
```

which prints

```
['the', 'thinks', 'are']
```

---

**UPDATE** (Thanks to [@wwii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823755/wwii) for [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63074896/how-can-i-delete-elements-in-a-list-based-on-a-list-of-indexes-that-ive-already/63075099#comment111539519_63075099))

If the given `lst` is not sorted in ascending order, you can do like the following instead:

```py
lst = [3, 1, 5]
lost = ['the', 'cat', 'thinks', 'you', 'are', 'crazy']

for index in sorted(lst, reverse=True):  # descending index order
    del lost[index]
```

Comment: What if `lst = [3,1,5]`?

Comment: @wwii lol, I didn't even think of that! Thanks for your comment! Then, `for index in sorted(lst, reverse=True): del lost[index]` can be used instead.

Comment: @wwii I updated my post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your're not creating a list with `{}`, but a set. If you want to create a list you need to use the `[]` characters. After that you can remove the elements from the list like so:

```py
indexes = {1,3,5}
lst = ['the' , 'cat' , 'thinks' , 'you' , 'are' , 'crazy']

lst_dct = dict(enumerate(lst))
for index in indexes:
    lst_dct.pop(index)

new_lst = list(lst_dct.values())
```

The `new_lst` will now contain the remaining elements.

Also instead of the `remove` function, which requires an element, you need to use `pop` to remove and element from a list based on the index.

Comment: Your solution suffers from the same problem the OP is trying to solve.

Comment: @wwii You are correct, I changed my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Every time you delete an element from your list, say according to lost[i], traverse through lost from i to the end, and decrement all the values by 1.

Comment: And how would I do that with python?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using `list comprehension` like below:

```
lst = [1,3,5]
lost =['the' , 'cat' , 'thinks' , 'you' , 'are' , 'crazy' ]

print([ val for idx, val in enumerate(lost) if idx not in lst])
```

It would be : `['the', 'thinks', 'are']` Hope helps you

Comment: Does your solution work specifically because it is a list comprehension or can a for loop work? Does it work because it creates a new list instead of removing items from the original?

Comment: It'll work with a `for loop` as well, but you can solve it in a one-liner code. The main reason is that when you wanna delete items by their index you're gonna get in trouble because the length list changes every time

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension with condition too .

```
lst = [1,3,5]
lost =['the' , 'cat' , 'thinks' , 'you' , 'are' , 'crazy' ]
copy_list=[lost[i] for i in range(len(lost)) if not i in lst]
```

Comment: Can you do it with a for loop or does it work specifically because it is a list comprehension?

Comment: @wwii It could work for a loop too, just would be longer to write! List comprehension in the underlying layer implements the loop and makes the code readable.

Answer (score 0):

If space is not an issue, you can use this:

```py
import numpy as np

lst = [1, 3, 5]
lost =['the' , 'cat' , 'thinks' , 'you' , 'are' , 'crazy' ]
output = np.delete(lost, lst).tolist()
print(output)
```

output:

```
['the', 'thinks', 'are']
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over indexes
Append the ones that are not required

```
new = [lost[i] for i in range(len(lost)) if i not in lst]
```

Comment: Better: Use `enumerate` like this: `new = [word for index, word in enumerate(lost) if index not in lst]`. If `lst` is big you might want to make a `set` from it first to speed things up.